VSCode run C++ file terminal displays unexpected information
When I use VSCode to run a C++ file, for example
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    printf("Hello World!");
    return 0;
}

I click 'run c/c++ file' button, then the terminal shows:

In addition to the normal information in blue, it displays unexpected information in white, and the output of the program come right after the white information. If the program requires input, sometimes my imput will cover the white information. When debugging, this issue also occurs. And the white part is different each time:

However, if I use 'code runner', such problem wouldn't happen.
'tasks.json' file is automatically generated by vscode:
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\Users\\limuchen\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}

No 'launch.json' file.
Extensions installed:

I tried reinstall vscode (including its extensions) and mingw64, but it doesn't work. How can I remove the additional white information? Very grateful if someone can help me solve the issue.
Update:
I copied the blue code, pasted it in terminal and pressed enter, then the white code automatically came out:

Could it have anything to do with Github Copilot? But I have already deleted it completely.
Another finding is that once I drag the upper edge of the terminal window to change the size of the window, the white information disappears.

C:\\Users\\limuchen\\mingw64\\bin means you didn't follow the official VSCode instructions: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

For me the "Hello World" is on its own line after the command that is invoked to debug your task.

@drescherjm Thanks so much. But I followed the instructions and the white part remains. It seems doesn't work for me.

@user Sure, I updated the extension list in my question. Actually I did install copilot before, but after I reinstalled vscode and remove all its extensions ('.vscode' folder), I never installed copilot again.

Unwanted output in the terminal of VScode and Executing C++ in VS code is not Clean

@user12002570 I don't think this is the same issue. let's see what the asker has to say about the answers in those questions

@user12002570 I've read these questions and they're different cases from mine. My terminal output strange information, not only prompt information.

@user I newly find that once I drag the upper edge of the terminal window to change the size of the window, the white information disappears. Very thankful if you have any new idea.

@likelimc Did you using the solutions given in the two dupes? They should solve the issue.

@user12002570 The first solution doesn't work, but the second actually does. After I changed my default terminal from PowerShell to cmd, the issue was solved. So I wonder if this means there's a problem with my PS. Could you please give me guidance on how to fix it, should I reinstall PS? Thanks a lot for helping me out!
